# Mathematica Reduce function in Sympy

Tags: equation-solving, python

I am now using *Mathematica* to compare two big expressions with `Reduce` function. However, since these two expressions are very complicated, I can not get an answer from *Mathematica*. I decided to switch to Python Sympy. First of all, is Sympy more powerful than *Mathematica*? If yes, what is the equal expression for `Reduce` function in Python?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Chances are very high that you will have worse luck in SymPy. As far as a CAS goes Mathematica is likely the best...

Comment: While the border is blurred it sounds more like a Python question.